# Displaying a layout on multiple pages

Tags: php, html, css

i'm sure this has been answered before, but I haven't really been able to figure out how to word it in order to get the desired answer I'm looking for.

I'm creating a website for a local shop that one of my buddies own(mostly for the fact that I have an interest in web dev and everyone else was asking ~500 for it)

I know that I could just copy/paste the html into every page, but I'm wondering if that's the standard way to have multiple pages in a website? I'm trying to do a good job on this website as opposed to just throwing it together and handing it over to him, plus it's a good learning experience to do things efficiently.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help!

Comment: you can just create a number of php include files, that could pull in the content on each page that is repeated, and then just change the content that is different.  If you have a lot of content, you could store it in a database, and generate it through a php/mysql connection

Comment: note 500 is very cheap for a good website.  your buddy should pay for quality

Comment: assuming, of course, that you mean American dollars and not Euros (which is actually still pretty cheap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you're looking for is [*templating*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_processor).

PHP itself is a templating language - you can mix code/HTML and include files inside other ones. This lets you share code across multiple pages. In the ideal case, you would have the logic in logic files, and only printing/looping constructs in template files.

[Here is a nice tutorial](http://phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-templating.html) that covers all the basics.

Comment: @KruSuPhy Please accept the answer if it was to your liking.